# No tag badge tracker?

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed that while checking your user activity on PLDI, there is no settings icon to determine whether you're tracking your next privilege or a tag badge:

[image]

Whereas there's normally a settings icon after the 'X rep.'

[image]

Do tag badges exist yet for PLDI? If not, do we get them when we move into Public Beta?

Answer (score 3):

There are no tags on the site [with enough questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395) to be eligible for a tag badge yet. There needs to be 100 tagged questions, and none has more than 77 currently. I don't believe private beta has any impact on that availability.